# How to embed images with blocks

Tags: blocks, media, nodes

Am newbie to Drupal this is my first question

i want to embed my images on the blocks body, so i tried below code to embed

```
<div class="topsection">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="topleftsection">
        <div class="socialmediaimage"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/facebook_top_hover.png',1)"><img src="sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/facebook_top.png" alt="Facebook" width="18" height="18" id="Image2" border="0" title="Facebook"></a></div>
        <div class="socialmediaimage"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image3','','sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/twitter_top_hover.png',1)"><img src="sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/twitter_top.png" alt="Twitter" width="18" height="18" id="Image3" border="0" title="Twitter"></a></div>
        <div class="socialmediaimage"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image4','','sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/gplus_top_hover.png',1)"><img src="sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/gplus_top.png" alt="Gplus" width="18" height="18" id="Image4" border="0" title="Gplus"></a></div>
        <div class="socialmediaimage"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image5','','sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/linkedin_top_hover.png',1)"><img src="sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/linkedin_top.png" alt="Linkedin" width="18" height="18" id="Image5" border="0" title="Linkedin"></a></div>
        <div class="socialmediaimage"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image6','','sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/skype_hover.png',1)"><img src="sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/skype.png" alt="Skype" width="18" height="18" id="Image6" border="0" title="FourBends"></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="toprightsection">
        <div class="emailsection">
          <div class="email">Email :</div>
          <div class="contacus"><a href="mailto:contactus@xxx.com">contactus@xxx.com</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="countrysection">
          <select name="Country" class="countrylist">
            <option>India</option>
            <option>USA</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

i having page.tpl and page--front.tpl in my custom theme, the images are only loading on page--front.tpl, please refer screenshot [image]

But for other pages for example user login page the images are not loading, please screenshot 2 [image]

When i inspect with firebug on the image src the url added with the "**user**" ,this is the reason behind why the images are not loading

http://localhost/projects/drupal/dev/user/sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/facebook_top.png

Comment: is your requirement to add social icons in a block ..???

Comment: Not only the social media icons, all the images, whatever the images am adding from the block body it't not loading

Comment: Are you created the block programmatically or just configured ..??

Comment: I created a region programmatically but i just added the block for that region as administrator

Comment: @Abin any guess ??

Comment: The select option and other settings are loading..??

Comment: @Abin everyting is working except the images

Comment: try by changing the images from your theme to 'sites/all/default/files/dir/' and change path as 'public://dir/'. am not sure it will help or not...

Comment: Nope no luck @Abin

Comment: is it has ant relation with tpl..?? do you rendered the block in tpl file.>?/

Comment: yep, am calling my blocks on tpl files like `<?php print render($page['header_social']); ?>`

Comment: Instead of calling from tpl  try through block configre.. like 'only the listed pages'.

Comment: @Abin what is the wrong with calling it from tpl files?

Comment: nothing wrong , just a try. am also following this approach. '  $block = block_load('name','delta');
    $output = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
    print render($output);'

Comment: @Abin No luck.. Really am worrying that the best CMS system doesn't having a simple option :(

Comment: The issue will be any minor ones, lets wait for an answer

Answer (score 1):

The image links are the problem here, I think. The images are shown on the front page but aren't shown on **other** pages. So, on the **front** page it understands the image link (by adding the `http://localhost/` in front of the image link you gave) but on the other pages, for example on `http://localhost/node/3` it tries to show an image from `http://localhost/node/3/sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/facebook_top.png` but there is **no** image on this address.

Therefore, use the **full** link (`http://localhost/sites/all/themes/custom/themename/images/facebook_top.png` etc).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if we use full url, while we move to the live or any other places we need to change it as well as, so it's not good idea

Comment: No, instead of using static url such as http: //localhost use a dynamic variable such as $base_url (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7). So no need to change the url if you change the domain name or base url.

Comment: Am embedding with body editor, so i don't want use php within the editor

Answer (score 0):

Click image to enlarge

[image]

You can do it by changing to the text format to Filtered HTML or Full HTML

Then you can do it manually by typing `<img src="url.jpg">` OR If you are using a module like [CK Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) you can add it through the icon bar.

Comment: i used both Filter HTML or Full HTML but no use, try to understand the question that realpath of the url is adding with image src that is the issue, i don't want to use CK Editor or CK Finder,i want to add it using Drupal body text editor

Comment: Can you edit your question, highlight your code and press the {} icon, your code is not showing up because you didn't add the code tags to it.

Comment: You should use the block tpl instead of node. When you hover the edit button for a block, in the bottom left corner of your browser you should see a url like admin/structure/block/manage/block/2/configure so in this case since you see the #2 you use block--block--2.tpl.php

Comment: I suggest you move out the images folder from the drupal/sites/all/themes/mytheme folder and just move it to drupal/images so your code changes to Ex: `<img src="images/facebook_top.png"`

Comment: but it's not the structure i think. both are the just tricks, this is weird a famous CMS system don't have the simple option

Comment: @JothiKannan Just to clear this up, what you're experiencing is not something Drupal is doing. Drupal will never randomly add a string to paths, it's either something you have set in config (Drupal or web server), or a misbehaving custom or contributed module (or even theme)

Comment: Am not using any server, it's happening in localhost too ;(